# Click event not firing while using Knockjs

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have the following code, it is embedded in a databinding using knockout.js

```
  <div data-bind="foreach {data:movies}">
     <div class="content-item full bottom-border">
        <div class="content-item-container">            
           <div class="movie-listing-header">
               <a class="icon arrow" data-bind="click: $parent.arrow"></a>
               <div class="movie-details">
                    <div class="title">
                       <a href="#" data-bind="text: MovieName, attr: { href: DetailsUrl }"></a>
                    </div> 
                    <div class="info">
                        <div>                      
                            <span class="rating" data-bind="css: 'rating-' + (MovieRating || 'NR').toLowerCase().replace(/-/, '')"></span> 
                        </div>                        
                    </div>
               </div>
            <a class="icon right-arrow"></a>      
          </div>
        <div class="showtimes">
             <div data-bind="template: { name: 'movie-grouped-showtimes-template', data: $data }"></div>    
        </div>    
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

I am trying to have the "icon arrow" process the following js script when pressed:

```
 $('.icon.arrow').click(function () {
        var active_el = $(this);
        $('.movie-listing-header').each(function () {
            if ($(this).get(0) === active_el.parent().get(0)) {

                if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {
                    $(this).siblings('.showtimes').hide();
                } else {
                    $(this).siblings('.showtimes').show();
                }
                $(this).toggleClass('active');

            } else {
                $(this).removeClass('active');
                $(this).siblings('.showtimes').hide();
            }
        });

    });
```

the above code works fine in another program not using knockout.js, also it works when I tried firing the "Icon arrow" outside of the knockout.js binding.

I have tired to code a function inside of my view model, hoping that it would fire off this javascript, but no luck. Any ideas

Comment: Why are you trying to handle a click using jQuery? This logic should be in your view model.

Comment: I didn't write the jquery it was provided for me by my front end guy, is there a way to hide "showtimes" in my view model, I guess I will have to research this. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that your adding the `click` handler **BEFORE** calling `applyBindings` on your html.
In another words you defined the `click` handler **BEFORE** is even created by Knockout `foreach` binding.

To explain it, for example suppose we have html like this:

```
<div data-bind="foreach: list">
    <button class="btn" data-bind="text: $data"></button>
    <br/>
</div>
```

And JS code like this:

```
$('.btn').on('click', function () {
    console.log('clicked');
});
var vm = {
    list: ko.observableArray(["first", "second"])
};
ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

Whenever you click on buttons nothing will happen because there is no html markup for the buttons yet.
To solve it you have 2 options.

1. Define your `click` handler after `applyBindings`.
2. Use jQuery `.live` or `.on` to bind your handler when there is selector match `$('.icon.arrow')`

like this:

```
$(document).on('click', '.btn', function () {
    console.log('clicked');
});
```

I hope i got you right!